# Reverse DNS works on our Bind9 server, not anywhere else

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Up until a couple of days ago, our reverse DNS for our class C IP space was working fine. Now, other mail servers are reporting that they cannot find the RDNS response for the IP address of our outgoing mail server.

When we try to query our own DNS server for an IP address in our class C, the server responds properly:

```
$ host 206.12.82.4 206.12.82.130
Using domain server:
Name: 206.12.82.130
Address: 206.12.82.130#53
Aliases: 

4.82.12.206.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer smtp.lightspeed.ca.
4.82.12.206.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ns2.lightspeed.ca.
```

If you ask 8.8.8.8 for the RDNS on any of our IP addresses, it fails:

```
$ host 206.12.82.4 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

Host 4.82.12.206.in-addr.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

I personally don't think I have any control over this, and it's an issue with the DNS servers from the company that assigned our IP address space. This hasn't happened to me in the 17 years I've been working here.

Comment: Well if you do a `dig +trace dd.cc.bb.aa.in-addr.arpa` from some outside system does delegations all look right?

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? This is a bit too vague for us to help. Did you already contact your ISP or "the company that assigned your IP address space"?

Comment: It turns out to be the company that provided the IP space, combined with an ancient DNS record combined with an old expired domain name.

Answer (score 2):

You can contact your IP provider and ask them to delegate control over the IPs to you, or you can ask them to update your RDNS for you. If they've not delegated access to you, then you're right it's out of your control but your provider will surely update any records you require.